# C - Declaring an array with an undefined value

Tags: c

I am trying to determine the size of an array by having the user input the size of the array after being prompted (because I don't know how many grades I'll have per test)...

It doesnt seem to like the line where `scanf ("%c",&grades[i]);`

Here is the whole function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main (void)
{
int numGrades;
char grades;
char i;
int x;


printf ("Enter The Amount Of Numbers In Your Array: ");
scanf("%i", &numGrades);/*Stores Amount Of Grades In The Array*/

for (x = 0; x < numGrades; ++x)
  {
  printf ("\nEnter the grade: ");
  scanf ("%c",&grades[i]);
  }

return 0; 
}
```

How can I pass the array size as a parameter so that I can accept an array of any size? (I will be adding a function that will take all the grades and combine them together by letter)

Comment: Change `char grades` to `char* grades`. And after `scanf`, do this. `grades = malloc(numGrades);`

Comment: `grades` is supposed to be an array (or a pointer to char), not a single `char`

Comment: Grades is defined as single character

Comment: @icepack.. Is there a problem with my suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. If your compiler support C99 variable length arrays you could declare the array after you get the size:

   ```
   scanf("%i", &numGrades);
   char grades[numGrades];
   ```
2. If not then you have to dynamically allocate the array on the heap:

   ```
   scanf("%i", &numGrades);
   char *grades = malloc(numGrades * (sizeof *grades));
   ```

Comment: I would just note that VLA's created from user input are a horrible idea (if not just a horrible idea in general...).  Use `malloc`.  Also, `sizeof(char)` is defined to always be `1`.

Comment: VLAs created on unchecked user input sizes are a bad idea.  If you've checked the size for sanity (strictly positive — not zero, not negative — and not too large for some nebulous definition of 'too large', perhaps 4 KiB or 64 KiB), then there's not likely to be any harm done.

Comment: About the `sizeof(char)` thing, just future-proofing in case the OP wants to use some other type. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, then use `sizeof *grades`.

Answer (score 2):

You declared `grades` as a single `char`, not an array.  Either move the declaration to after you read in `numGrades` and make it a VLA, like this:

```
char grades[numGrades];
```

Or use dynamic allocation:

```
char *grades = malloc(numGrades);
```

If you choose the latter, don't forget to `free()` it.