# Trouble: C Declaration of integer array of unknown size

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors

I need to read unknown amount of various numbers on user's input using `scanf` function. That simply means the number of various integers is determined by the user by sending as many numbers as he can. Note that I read directly the numbers (I have to), as stated in following code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int numbers[];
    int error = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while(scanf("%i", &numbers[i++]) == 1);

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(numbers) - 1; ++i) {
        if(numbers[i] < -10000 || numbers[i] > 10000)
        {
            printf("%i%s", numbers[i], ", ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s", "\b\b\nError: Error: Vstup je mimo interval!\n");
            // Means "Input is out of range!".
            // We have to write exact output to terminal as stated in HW.
            i = sizeof(numbers);
            error = 1;
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

The `int error` is actually a boolean value, but I am lazy to implement boolean library, so I define it as integer :D

However, the problem is elsewhere. Compiler throws me an error:

```
main.c:7:9: error: array size missing in ‘numbers’
     int numbers[];
                ^
```

Looks like that C program need to know the allocable size of an array. I already looked into some codes others have shared there to find out basics I need to implement and while searching for the array size issue, I found this question:

[C - Declaring an array with an undefined value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264613/c-declaring-an-array-with-an-undefined-value)

However, it does not solve the problem with unknown array size for direct input of unknown amount of numbers. I found nowhere exactly I need to solve. I tried to define maximum size of array to hold up to 999 numbers, but then compiler throws me this exception:

```
main.c:50:23: error: iteration 999u invokes undefined behavior [-Werror=aggressive-loop-optimizations]
             if(numbers[j] > 0)
                       ^
main.c:48:9: note: containing loop
         for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(numbers); ++j)
         ^
```

Same for every loop used for numbers statistics (total amount, maximum, minimum, odds, evens, positives, negatives, their percentage and average). That means the array is strictly size of 999 numbers with rest of numbers being zeros. I found out a `malloc` function, but do not understand its usage :(

Comment: For malloc: You want to declare the array as `int *arr`, then, before usage, have `arr = (int*) malloc(n * sizeof(int) );`, where n is the size you need, and at the end of the function you should call `free(arr);`.

Comment: For real issue: An array of size 999 has indices from 0 to 998 as valid.

Comment: Further: `typedef enum {false, true} bool;` is *enough* to implement boolean.

Comment: Do you actually have to store the inputs, or just keep track of how many have been entered?

Comment: Also, C99 provides the Boolean type `_Bool` in `stdbool.h`.

Comment: @PaulStelian: Thank you. It compiles now, however `scanf` is in an infinite loop :( It scans numbers forever :( Then it returns the out of range error message declared in the code when exited with Ctrl+D after line break (as terminate just after numbers does not work) :( The `typedef` works just like a charm. May I have missed something? :(

Comment: @JohnBode: I need to store the inputs as I am operating with them (calculating mins, maxes, and other numbers statistics). And I need to display it in right format to be accepted by recognition machine.

Comment: @JohnBode: Strictly, strictly, C99 provides the `_Bool` type even without the `<stdbool.h>` header; the header provides `bool`, `true`, `false` (and `__bool_true_false_are_defined`).  But your main point is that C99 has support for a boolean type, and that's correct.

Comment: To make clear: I need to input numbers in a single input. I do not know the amount of numbers. I can't find anything that would fit into my problem. The while loop keeps asking for input, it never ends until I terminate the input by Ctrl+D keystroke. Does any other solution than while loop exist for this task?

Comment: Note that `sizeof()` returns a size in bytes.  If it worked on your array (if your array definition worked), then `or(int j = 0; j < sizeof(numbers); ++j)` would be trying to index `sizeof(int)` times too far into the array.  It would have been better if you'd shown the second lot of code, but it appears that you defined `int numbers[999];` which can only be indexed with values 0..998, but if `sizeof(int) == 4` (most common size), then your loop would have tried indexing elements 999 .. 3995, none of which exist in the array.  Hence the compiler warning.

Comment: There is no mechanism in C to read an indefinite number of integers in a single I/O operation.  You have to either know the number in advance or iterate reading some appropriate smaller set of numbers at a time (e.g. one at a time).  You could write a function to do the job.  How else should the end of the input be detected than by EOF?  There are a limited number of ways to tell when you need to exit the loop: EOF, non-numeric input, prior count — did I miss any?  A sentinel value (such as -999999) is a variant on 'non-numeric input', I suppose — it is numeric but has a special meaning.

Comment: This is exactly what dynamic allocation is for, and in C, you use `malloc()` (or `calloc()`) to perform dynamic allocation. Can you explain what you don't understand about `malloc()`?

Comment: Okay thank you all for your shares. I'm glad of the 2 answers. Anyway, it's not the way I really needed. I contacted proffessor and he recommended me a simple way to ensure the function the program has to have: just enclose the numbers' calculation inside the `while` loop and that `scanf` function does not return number of successfully scanned inputs but straight scanned value, which I had to test for the EOF char (0x0a). Anyway, the program does not need to be robust, it needed to meet input and ouput requirements tested by prepared input and output files... Thank you all, marking as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I need to read **unknown amount** of various numbers on user's input using scanf function." is a poor design goal.

Any program that allows an externally interface to input *any* amount of input without bound is a hacker exploit.

Robust code limits user input to a generous, but sane input amount.  Good code will code that upper bound as a constant or macro.

Using `scanf()` is not the best tool to read user input.
Recommend `fgets()` to read a *line*. (Not shown here.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// find the next character without consuming it.
int peek_ch(void) {
  unsigned char ch;
  if (scanf("%c", &ch) == 1) {
    ungetc(ch, stdin);
    return ch;
  }
  return EOF;
}

#define INPUT_N 1000
void foo(void) {
  int input[INPUT_N];
  size_t n = 0;

  // Read 1 _line_ of input using `scanf("%d", ....)` to read one `int` at a time
  for (n = 0; n < INPUT_N; n++) {
    int ch;
    while (((ch = peek_ch()) != '\n') && isspace(ch))
      ;
    // %d consume leading white-space including \n, hence the above code to find it.
    if (scanf("%d", &input[n]) != 1) {
      break;
    }
  }

  // TBD: Add code to handle case when n == N

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%zu: %d\n", i, input[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description in the comments, you're going to have to allocate memory dynamically with `malloc` and extend it with `realloc` as necessary.

Here's a basic skeleton of an example:

```
#define INITIAL_SIZE 1024

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  size_t arraySize = 0;
  size_t i = 0;

  // initially allocate numbers array
  int *numbers = malloc( sizeof *numbers * INITIAL_SIZE );
  if ( !numbers )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Error allocating memory...exiting\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }

  arraySize = INITIAL_SIZE;
  int input;
  while ( scanf( "%d", &input ) == 1 )
  { 
    if ( i == arraySize )
    {
      // double the size of the numbers array
      int *tmp = realloc( numbers, sizeof *numbers * (2 * arraySize) );
      if ( !tmp )
      {
        fprintf( stderr, "Could not extend array size...no more inputs allowed\n" );
        break;
      }
      numbers = tmp;
      arraySize *= 2;
    }
    numbers[i++] = input;
  }

  // process numbers
  ...
  // clean up after ourselves
  free( numbers );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, I really appreciate that. It helped me, though what I really needed wasn't that one solution, but slightly different. As stated in comment above, I needed to only meet homework input and output requirements. I contacted my proffessor and he suggested me to get rid of integer array and enclose initial numbers list output and all calculation progress inside the `while` loop. The final calculation for percentage and average sumation is then wrapped in `if` condition testing if an error did not occured completed with all final output. This, however, isn't going to be marked as a solving answer as it really helped me alot here. But I marked as answer by chux as it's very logical and any program should be protected against malware exploit by buffer overflow. Again thank you all for your help, I really appreciate that :)